# curl_setopt() expects parameter 1 to be resource - CURL Issue

Tags: php, curl

I have one issue in my code, I would like get info through CURL (little payment gateway) but i have the next issue...

Warning: curl_setopt() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/xxxxxx/public_html/xxxxxxx/myaccount/xxxx.php on line 12

And I have the next code lines..

```
$getbin  = 'https://binlist.net/json/".$bin."';
    $get  = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $getbin);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $exec  = curl_exec($get);
    curl_close($get);
    $cc           = json_decode($exec);
    $ccbrand      = $cc->brand;
    $ccbank       = $cc->bank;
    $cctype       = $cc->card_type;
    $ccklas       = $cc->card_category;
```

Can you help me? Thank you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're setting the `curl_setopt` [options](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) to `$curl`, but initialize a new session (and return a cURL handle) to `$get`. You should change your `curl_setopt` lines like so:

```
curl_setopt($get, CURLOPT_URL, $getbin);
curl_setopt($get, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($get, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

This way, you're setting the options for the cURL handle `$get`.

Comment: I tried it, but it doesnt give me the informarion through cURL, i think the problem is the server.